# graphviz wide flat tree structure with right angles

Tags: graph, tree, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have a monster of a tree I'm attempting to visualize in graphviz using dot. Specifically, I want to use orthogonal branches with shared edges because some of my nodes have an out-degree of ~20 (max, most are closer to 3-5).

What I want is something like this (forgive the terrible paint job):

[image: desired]

I've done a bunch of reading about using hidden nodes to get this, and have this code

```
digraph {
    splines="ortho"
    rankdir="LR"
    concentrate="true"
    aa [shape=none, label="", width=0, height=0]
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    H
    I
    A -> aa [arrowhead="none"]
    aa -> B
    aa -> C
    aa -> D
    aa -> E
    aa -> F
    aa -> G
    aa -> H
    aa -> I
}
```

But what I'm getting is this:

[image: broken]

This approach works great with 3 or so child nodes, but breaks down immediately in a larger use case. Turning "concentrate" on or off doesn't have much impact (a very slight improvement).

My current plan is to abandon this approach and try using "record" style nodes and stack them up manually, but that's going to be a bunch more work so I'm hoping someone else has a better suggestion. I'm a bit flexible on how this looks, basically I just want to visualize a tree with ~600 nodes as a giant image like this

I am actually generating this from python, in case that makes a difference (I'd be willing to use another python library if it would help)

EDIT: One painful hack I discovered is to use a 0 width and Y height box instead of the single point hidden node, the problem is you have to fuss with the spacing and it's still not quite right. This is what I've got so far, but I'm leaving this open hoping someone has a better idea:

```
digraph {
    splines="ortho"
    rankdir="LR"
    nodesep=0.3
    aa [shape=box, label="", width=0, height=5.6]
    node [shape=box, height=0.5]
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    H
    I
    A -> aa [arrowhead="none"]
    aa -> B [headport="w"]
    aa -> C [headport="w"]
    aa -> D [headport="w"]
    aa -> E [headport="w"]
    aa -> F [headport="w"]
    aa -> G [headport="w"]
    aa -> H [headport="w"]
    aa -> I [headport="w"]
}
```

[image: kinda_broken]

In this case, I have N=8 nodes with height *h* and separation *s*, so I make the height of the box `(N-1)*(h+s)` to cover until the middle of the boxes on the top and bottom, but I wind up with overhang because I can't quite control the tail point properly. Not sure how well this will scale to a bigger tree

EDIT 2: As expected, this doesn't work at all on the more complex graph because I have no way to know how far apart the boxes on the right will be (they get spaced out to make room for other nodes)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after messing around a bit I came up with a workable solution. Using "ortho", "lines" or "polyline" as the spline method, you can create one (invisible) "joint" node *per* outgoing state, as follows:

```
 digraph {
    splines="ortho"
    rankdir="LR"

    node [shape=box]
    A B C D E F G H I

    node [shape=none, label="", width=0.0, height=0.0]
    {
        rank=same;
        bb->cc->dd->ee->ff->gg->hh->ii [arrowhead="none"]
    }

    A->bb [arrowhead="none"]

    bb -> B
    cc -> C
    dd -> D
    ee -> E
    ff -> F
    gg -> G
    hh -> H
    ii -> I
}
```

Which produces this:

[image: kind of working]

This kind of scales to bigger graphs and looks alright (I find polylines to be the best spline method for a larger tree). The main annoying part is that you have to decide which joint to point "A" at (it can't just generically point somewhere on the line, or the middle of the line). This can create some headaches with larger trees